# Adding JPanels and Painting to JInternalFrames

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, paint

Is it possible to add a JPanel with an outline and painted content to a JInternalFrame? In other words, something like the following:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();

JInternalFrame iframe = new JInternalFrame();

JPanel panel = new JPanel();

iframe.setVisible(true);
iframe.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

iframe.add(panel)
desktop.add(iframe);
frame.setContentPane(desktop);

panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
panel.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

and in the paint function (within the JFrame class) have

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    graphics.//insert method
}
```

and still have it show up inside the panel within the JInternalFrame.

For whatever reason, neither the JPanel nor any painting features showed up. Could anybody help me understand how to accomplish this or explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

> and in the paint function (within the JFrame class) have

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics){
    graphics.//insert method
}
```

Don't override the paint() method of a JFrame. There is rarely any reason do to this. This will cause a problem because you broke the painting method and now the child components won't be painted.

A JInterrnalFrame is just like a JFrame (or JDialog). You can add any component to it.

```
iframe.setVisible(true);
iframe.setSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
iframe.add(panel)
```

Also, add components to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible. Then the layout managers can do their job.